# What about $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[n]{2}]$?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Most textbooks talk about $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ but I haven't succeed in my search of **direct** references about $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[n]{d}]$.

I would like to ask about $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[n]{2}]$ for $n>2$. I know it inherits the norm from $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[n]{2})$, but what is it known about $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[n]{2}]$? Is it a euclidean domain, or a unique factorization domain, or at least a GCD domain? Can their prime or irreducible elements be clasiffied as nicely as in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-1}]$? I will be very grateful with answers or references for this questions, even for just $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$.

Thank you.

Comment: The quadratic fields are a lot easier to deal with, mainly because $x^2-dy^2=1$ always has a solution, and the associated continued fractions are periodic.

Comment: For the question of integral bases see https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/integersradical.pdf .

Comment: @franz-lemmermeyer Thanks. I know this reference, but it could be my lack of understanding in algebraic number theory that I cannot see direct answers to my questions there.

Comment: It means in particular that the claim by Kenny concerning the integral basis is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The discriminant of $\alpha=\sqrt[3]{2}$ is $\pm 27\cdot 4$, so only $2$ and $3$ may ramify, since $\pm 27\cdot 4=[\mathcal{O}_K:\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]]^2 d_K$, where $K=\Bbb Q\!\left(\sqrt[3]2\right)$.

Now $\mu_\alpha=X^3-2$ is $2$-Eisenstein, so $2\nmid  [\mathcal{O}_K:\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]]$ and $\mu_{\alpha}(X-1)$ is $3$-Eisenstein, so  $3\nmid  [\mathcal{O}_K:\mathbb{Z}[\alpha +1]]=  [\mathcal{O}_K:\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]]$. Therefore,  $\mathcal{O}_K=\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ and $d_K=\pm 27\cdot 4$. It follows that the factorisation of $(p)$ into prime ideals is reflected by the decomposition of $X^3-2$ modulo $p$.

The  Minkoswki bound is $\approx 2.94$, hence the class group is generated by the class of prime ideals lying above $2$. Now, since $(2)=(\alpha,2)^3=(\alpha)^3$, the unique prime ideal above $2$ is $(\alpha)$, which is principal, so $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ is a PID. A conjecture (supported by lot of positive results) suggests that a ring of integers is a PID if and only it is Euclidean (but not necessarily norm Euclidean, so the Euclidean function may be very hard to find).

Since $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ is a PID, irreducible elements are exactly the generators of prime ideals. Depending of the factorisation of $X^3-2$ mod $p$, you will have.

For $p\neq 2,3$:

If $2$ is not a cube modulo $p$, $p$ is irreducible

If $2$ is a cube modulo $p$ but $X^2+X+1$ is irreducible modulo $p$, we have $(p)=P_1P_2$, where $P_1=(\alpha-m,p), P_2=(\alpha^2+m\alpha+m^2,p)$n where $m^3\equiv 2 \ [p]$.

The generators $\pi_1,\pi_2$ of $P_1,P_2$ will give you non associate irreducible elements.

If $2$ is a cube modulo $p$ and $X^2+X+1$ is reducible modulo $p$, whe have $(p)=P_1P_2P_3$, where $P_k=(\alpha-j^km,p)$ with $j^2+j+1\equiv 0 \ [p]$ and $m^3\equiv 2 \ [p]$.

The generators $\pi'_1,\pi_2',\pi'_ 3$ of $P_1,P_2,P_3$ will give you non associate irreducible elements.

If $p=2$, we get that $\alpha$ is irreducible

If $p=3$, $(3)=P^3$, where $P=(\alpha-1,3)=(\alpha-1)$ , hence $\alpha-1$ is irreducible.

Hence, up to association, the irreducible elements are $\alpha,\alpha-1$ and the various $\pi_1,\pi_2,\pi'_1,\pi'_2,\pi'_3$. I doubt that you can find the last ones explicitely for general $p$...

Comment: This is very enlightening. I confess I still have some way to go to understand this answer in full, but it gives me a good perspective of some stuff I was thinking intuitively.
Considering the subcases when $2$ is a cube modulo $p$, this makes me think that $p$ is associated with $\pi_1\pi_2$ (or with $\pi'_1\pi'_2\pi'_3$ in the other subcase) which allows to conclude that some $\pi_i$ (or some $\pi'_j$ in the other subcase) has norm $p$. This looks obvious, but please let me know if I'm saying something wrong.

Comment: If $2$ is a cube but $X^2+X+1$ is irreducible mod $p$, $\pi_1$ will have norm $p$, while $\pi_2$ will have norm $p^2$. If $X^2+X+1$ is reducible mod $p$, $\pi'_1,\pi'_2,\pi'_3$ will all have norm $p$.

Answer (score 2):

According to [LMFDB - The L-functions and Modular Forms Database](https://www.lmfdb.org/):

- [$\Bbb Z\!\left[\sqrt[3]2\right]$is a Principal Ideal Domain](https://www.lmfdb.org/NumberField/3.1.108.1).
- [$\Bbb Z\!\left[\sqrt[4]2\right]$ is a Principal Ideal Domain](https://www.lmfdb.org/NumberField/4.2.2048.1).
- [$\Bbb Z\!\left[\sqrt[5]2\right]$ is a Principal Ideal Domain](https://www.lmfdb.org/NumberField/5.1.50000.1).
- [$\Bbb Z\!\left[\sqrt[6]2\right]$ is a Principal Ideal Domain](https://www.lmfdb.org/NumberField/6.2.1492992.4).
- [$\Bbb Z\!\left[\sqrt[7]2\right]$ is a Principal Ideal Domain](https://www.lmfdb.org/NumberField/7.1.52706752.1).
- [$\Bbb Z\!\left[\sqrt[8]2\right]$ is a Principal Ideal Domain](https://www.lmfdb.org/NumberField/8.2.2147483648.2).
- [$\Bbb Z\!\left[\sqrt[9]2\right]$ is a Principal Ideal Domain](https://www.lmfdb.org/NumberField/9.1.99179645184.2).
- [$\Bbb Z\!\left[\sqrt[10]2\right]$ is a Principal Ideal Domain](https://www.lmfdb.org/NumberField/10.2.5120000000000.4).
- [$\Bbb Z\!\left[\sqrt[11]2\right]$ is a Principal Ideal Domain](https://www.lmfdb.org/NumberField/11.1.292159150705664.1).
- [$\Bbb Z\!\left[\sqrt[12]2\right]$ is a Principal Ideal Domain](https://www.lmfdb.org/NumberField/12.2.18260173718028288.30).
- [$\Bbb Z\!\left[\sqrt[20]2\right]$ is a Principal Ideal Domain](https://www.lmfdb.org/NumberField/20.2.54975581388800000000000000000000.1) assuming [GRH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Riemann_hypothesis).
- [$\Bbb Z\!\left[\sqrt[40]2\right]$ is a Principal Ideal Domain](https://www.lmfdb.org/NumberField/40.2.6646139978924579364519035301401722880000000000000000000000000000000000000000.1) assuming [GRH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Riemann_hypothesis).

There must be something fishy going on...

Methodology: the link says that an integral basis is $1, a, a^2, \cdots$ which means that $\Bbb Z\!\left[\sqrt[n]2\right]$ is the ring of integers of $\Bbb Q\!\left(\sqrt[n]2\right)$, and it also says that the class number is $1$, which means that the ring is a Principal Ideal Domain.